# Use ros2-FastRTPS with standalone FastRTPS programs

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to create some publisher in ros2 with Fast-RTPS as middleware and on the other side receive published topics on the standalone (non ros2) FastRTPS programs?

I've even created an .idl file with simple string message (compiles with colcon and copied to eProsima project directory. Next I've created header with fastrtpsgen tool). But the topics don't see each other...

Knows somewhere the right rules/setting for my goal?

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319723/use-ros2-fastrtps-with-standalone-fastrtps-programs/) by [murokill](https://answers.ros.org/users/39866/murokill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-27**:
Duplicate: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/269

Please don't ask multiple versions of questions that's poor etiquette as it potentially causes multiple people to try to help you. Also your other question has much more helpful details that might be able to help someone answer your question here. Please see our support guidelines: https://wiki.ros.org/Support

Since this is a question this is the right place so I'll close the other one. Please edit your question here to add more details. The easier it is for someone to reproduce your problem the easier it is for them to help you.

**Comment by [slmat27](https://answers.ros.org/users/34497/slmat27/) on 2019-04-03**:
@**murokill** were you able to reach a solution for the issue or is it still pending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@murokill, I've been fighting the same battle. I was just able to get the ROS2 `examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher` and `examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber` working with a variant of the eProsima Fast-RTPS code generated by pretty much following the steps on the eProsima Fast-RTPS [Getting Started](https://fast-rtps.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/introduction.html) page. I pulled the `String.idl` IDL file from my ROS2 installation in place of the sample IDL snippet shown in the webpage. On my system, it was at `/opt/ros/crystal/share/std_msgs/msg`. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. There were two things I had to do to get it to work beyond the basic stuff you find fairly easily in tutorials. I used WireShark to dig into the RTPS UDP and Multicast packets to help clue me in on these updates.

**1.** In eProsima's code generated from your String.idl file, you'll need to prefix your topic in `StringPublisher::init()` and `StringSubscriber::init()` with `rt`. This tells eProsima Fast-RTPS that you are trying to talk with ROS2 nodes. I found this tidbit here in [ROS2 documentation](https://design.ros2.org/articles/topic_and_service_names.html#private-namespace-substitution-character). For example, my topic was `/hailstate` for the ROS2 publisher/subscriber and I wanted it to be the same on the eProsima publisher/subscriber, but it wasn't showing up that way. Once I prefixed my topic with `rt`, the topic names matched. Code below is the updated code that was generated using `fastrtpsgen -example CMake String.idl` in generated file `StringPublisher.cxx`. The same change on the last line would need to be made in the `StringSubscriber.cxx`:

```
 bool StringPublisher::init() {
     ParticipantAttributes PParam;
     PParam.rtps.builtin.domainId = 0;
     PParam.rtps.builtin.leaseDuration = c_TimeInfinite;
     PParam.rtps.setName("epro_publisher");
     mp_participant = Domain::createParticipant(PParam);
     if(mp_participant == nullptr)
     {
         return false;
     }
 
     Domain::registerType(mp_participant,
     static_cast<TopicDataType*>(&myType));
 
     // Create Publisher
 
     PublisherAttributes Wparam;
     Wparam.topic.topicKind = NO_KEY;
     Wparam.topic.topicDataType = myType.getName();
     Wparam.topic.topicName = "rt/hailstate";
```

**2.** My next problem was that my types didn't match. When running four nodes (ROS2 examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher, ROS2 examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber, eProsima subscriber, and eProsima publisher), the `ros2 topic list -t` command would show my topic with two different types. One type for the eProsima topic `std_msgs::msg::String` and a different type for the ROS2 topic `std_msgs/String` even though I used the ROS String.idl file to create the eProsima logic. Because of this type mismatch, the topics were still technically different. I changed the topic in the constructor, `StringPubSubType::StringPubSybType()`, in the `fastrtpsgen` generated file, `StringPubSubTypes.cxx`, with the line `setName("std_msgs::msg::dds_::String_");` line shown in the code snippet below. I just changed the type from the default specified by eProsima to what it shows now. After this, all four nodes started communicating with each other. The key is inserting the `dds_::` and adding the `_` at the end of the String base type.

> ```
> namespace std_msgs {
>     namespace msg  {
>         StringPubSubType::StringPubSubType() 
>         {
>             setName("std_msgs::msg::dds_::String_");
> ```

If there is a way to do this without feeling like I had to hack it, I'd be very interested to know what it is. I've started digging a little deeper into ROS2 msg and srv files to see if there is a better way to generate code that will work for ROS2 and eProsima without having to manually update files.

---

Originally posted by [WeekendWar](https://answers.ros.org/users/41540/weekendwar/) with karma: 56 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alyasko](https://answers.ros.org/users/41596/alyasko/) on 2019-05-16**:
@WeekendWar hi!
I am facing the same problem with mismatching types (FastRTPS publisher type and ROS2 subscriber type). Would you please provide more details about how to create the same types for FastRTPS standalone app and ROS2 node?
For example if I want to send ROS2 std_msgs/String type, what should I put to FastRTPS IDL file?
If possible, provide code examples please.
Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

**Comment by [WeekendWar](https://answers.ros.org/users/41540/weekendwar/) on 2019-05-16**:
@Alyasko, I updated my answer with some formatting to help highlight the answers. I also added a few code snippets. These will make sense if you've generated your code using the `fastrtpsgen` tool from eProsima using the `-example` option. If not, then I recommend you go through the *Getting Started* mentioned in my posting above. Hope it helps.

**Comment by [Bearnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41870/bearnd/) on 2019-05-28**:
This post was very good and helped me to solve this my communication problem as well - thank you so much! Is there any way to adapt the way `fastrtpsgen` is generating the type name convention, e.g. changing the way ROS2 generates the IDL file?

**Comment by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on 2019-06-08**:
There's an example project that demonstrates talking between native FastRTPS and ROS2 [here](https://github.com/davidhodo/ros2_idl_demo) if it's useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For everyone still having this issue, I added a [fix to the FastRTPSGen tool](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS-Gen/pull/22) that through an argument passed to the `fastrrpsgen` script (`-typeros2`), the type naming will be generated with the structure compatible with ROS2 topics. So now there is no need to change the naming manually after generating the code.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) with karma: 210 on 2020-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1